# The security guard problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations

There was a security guard in a bank. In front of him were 100 lockers in rows of 10. He thought of something as he saw all the lockers were closed. He started opening all the lockers whose lock numbers were multiples of 1, then closed all lockers whose number was a multiple of 2,and did the same for 3 and so on. If the locker was open, he closed it, if closed, opened it. He went to open multiples of 1 (all),then 2,4,6,8...and then 3,6,9.. And then finally reached 100.

After all the opening and closing,in the end, how many lockers are open and how many closed?

Comment: The number of divisors determines the status of the locker at the end.

Comment: I know that the perfect square lockers will be open, primes closed, but how will you ensure that an amount of lockers are opened or closed?

Comment: What happens if the locker number has an even number of divisors? Will it be closed or opened at the end?

Comment: @Sigur I can see by observation that all the perfect squares have an odd number of divisors, and the rest have an even number. But how can that be proven to always be the case?

Comment: @Rohinb97 "I know that the perfect square lockers will be open, primes closed..." You are correct, but why do you know the primes will be closed? Does your reasoning extend to composite numbers? If so, which ones?

Comment: @Rohinb97, after you know that the number of divisors is the trick, you can use that any number is a product of prime numbers (up to powers). So if $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, how many divisors can you find? Don't forget that $1$ is also a divisor and it appears when you take all $a_i=0$. So what is the condition to have odd number of divisors?

Comment: @ZettaSuro If $n$ is not a perfect square then for every divisor $x$ there is another divisor $\frac{n}{x}$ of $n$ such that $x \neq \frac{n}{x}$ (since $n$ is not a perfect square). What this means is that the distinct divisors of $n$ come in pairs and thus the number of these must be even. Also, if $n$ is a perfect square then there is exactly one number $y$ such that $y = \frac{n}{y}$. All other divisors again come in pairs.

Comment: I wrote it by mistake. Now I've deleted the comment. Sorry @user14111...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** How many divisors does $7$ have? How many divisors does $8$ have? How many divisors does $9$ have? What's special about $9$ and why?

**Further Hint:** If $a$ divides $n$, then $n = ab$ by definition. For example, $2$ divides $8$ because $8 = 2 \cdot 4$. In this way, divisors arise naturally in pairs.

If the numbers appearing in these pairs are all distinct, then there will be an even number of divisors. For example, the divisors of $8$ (in pairs) are $1$ and $8$ and also $2$ and $4$.

What about when the numbers in the pair aren't distinct? This can *only* happen if $n = a \cdot a$ for some $a$ (that is, if $n$ is a perfect square). For example, the divisors of $9$ (in pairs) are $1$ and $9$ and also $3$ and $3$. We don't count the $3$ twice, of course, so we get an odd number of divisors.

Comment: Are you hinting me and testing me or telling the answer?

Comment: @Rohinb97, I think Austin has given you one heck of a hint. Now you mull on it.

Comment: See my comment above. How will you ensure that 78 or 53 is open or closed? Taking out prime factors is too lengthy, and perfect square and primes only solve half of problem.

Comment: @Rohinb97, see my comment below your post.

Comment: @Rohinb97 A locker will be flipped when *any* of its divisors is encountered, not just the prime ones. Divisors of $7$: $1$, $7$. Divisors of $8$: $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$. Divisors of $9$: $1$, $3$, $9$.

Comment: I agree to you @AustinMohr, but try to understand that taking out every numbers divisor is illogical. And even if you do it then what if the nos. Were till 1000? Primes and perfect squares only solve half the problem. What about composite numbers? You cannot definitely say that every composite no. Has even or odd no. Of divisors. I too have thought about this question but did not come up with an exact answer. I am using this question to basically find out how many numbers till 100 have even or odd number of factors.

Comment: "You cannot definitely say that every composite no. Has even or odd no. Of divisors." They can be classified without performing the entire factorization. If I pull out one divisor, I am left with another. For example, dividing $10$ by $2$ leaves me with $5$, which is another divisor. Thus, divisors always come in "pairs" regardless of whether it is prime or composite. The only thing to consider is that sometimes the members of that "pair" are the same, but this only happens in a very special case...

Comment: Zettasuro and austin, you both are right but austin, how many special cases can you find and in the end, what is the answer?

Comment: Rohin, have you looked at the comment from @Alraxite?

Comment: @Rohinb97 I don't know if the site alerts you to edits or not, but I have expanded my answer.

Comment: This might surely work. So 10 will be opened and 90 closed?

Comment: @Rohinb97 That's the answer I reached.

Comment: Thanks bro, I went mad thinking for it.