# Flipping coins: What's the rule that determines which coins will be showing "Tails" after 100 runs?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

There are 100 coins in a row, all showing "Heads".
A person is going through all of the coins and changes their status (heads > tails, tails > heads), according to the following rules:

1. On the first run, he changes the status of all coins
2. On the 2nd run, he changes the status of the even coins
3. On the 3rd run, he changes the status of the 3, 6, 9 ,12, ... coins
4. On the X run, he changes the status of the X, 2X, 3X, ... coins.

What's the rule that determines which coins will be showing "Tails" after 100 runs?

Comment: Did you try to compute the status of coins 1-10 after 100 runs? You know, so that the question shows some personal input and maybe, maybe, to get an idea of the result...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The security guard problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408109/the-security-guard-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coins whose positions are perfect squares will end up in the opposite state (i.e., tails up), because a perfect square has an **odd** number of divisors:

- $ 1$ has $1$ divisor ($1$)
- $ 4$ has $3$ divisors ($1,2,4$)
- $ 9$ has $3$ divisors ($1,3,9$)
- $16$ has $5$ divisors ($1,2,4,8,16$)
- $25$ has $3$ divisors ($1,5,25$)
- $\dots$

Any other value (i.e. non-perfect square) has an **even** number of divisors, and therefore the coins at those positions will end up in the initial state (i.e., heads up).

Comment: @Flexsin Flex: Please note that I left the part of proving that a natural number has an odd number of natural divisors if and only if it is a perfect square (shouldn't be too hard if you observe the fundamental difference between the group of divisors of a perfect square and the group of divisors of a non-perfect square).